# Ubuntu 18.04: No sound with i3wm

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, i3-wm

I recently partitioned my system with a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04. Everything has been working fine so far, until I switched to i3. Whenever I use i3, there is no sound. I am using i3 version 4.13.1.

My first thought was to reinstall `pulseaudio`. That seemed to be fine. I then thought that maybe `alsamixer` had my volume muted somehow, but nothing seemed to be the problem there. `alsamixer` works just how I would expect, allowing me to turn up and down the volume for master, etc, but still no sound comes out of my speakers.

The sound card `alsamixer` has listed for me is HDA Intel PCH and the chip is Realtek ALC298.

I looked on `pactl list` and saw that my Sources and Sinks were suspended, so I tried disabling `module-suspend-on-idle` in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, but that did not change anything.

I'm very new to this stuff so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Have you tried using `pavucontrol` yet?